# Another private/auth not found thread in postfix-dovecot combo

Tags: email, debian, postfix, dovecot

If I try to send mails through my relay I get:

```
warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth_dovecot failed: No such file or directory
fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
```

The auth part in `main.cf`:

```
disable_vrfy_command = yes

smtpd_sasl_type        = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path        = private/auth_dovecot
#smtpd_sasl_path=/var/spool/postfix/private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
```

The auth provider in dovecot

```
unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
  mode = 0666
  user = postfix
  group = postfix
}
```

what `dovecot -n` says:

```
protocols = " imap pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
  group = postfix
  mode = 0666
  user = postfix
  }
}
```

I'm running on a debian 7.0 machine with Kernel 3.2.0-4-amd64 with dovecot 2.1.7

I googled and tried a lot solutions, but I can not get it working. Maybe somebody has an idea how to solve this or at least how to get some more information to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Based on main.cf, Postfix will connect to socket `private/auth_dovecot` relative to `/var/spool/postfix`. Unfortunately, based on `dovecot -n` output, dovecot only provide socket in `/var/spool/postfix/private/auth`.

So, this misconfiguration explain why postfix throw error `No such file or directory`